# access outer "this" in Javascript sort method

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function some_object(...) {
   this.data = {...};

   this.do_something = function(...) {
      var arr = [...];

      arr.sort(function (a, b) {
         return this.data[a] - this.data[b];
      });  
   }
}
```

However it's not working I think because `this` cannot be accessed in `sort` - another `this` is seen there for some reason, not the `this` of enclosing outer object.

What to do? thanks

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The different `this` is because the the anonymous function (its own closure) called by `arr.sort` calls the function with `this` being set to a different item than your main object. In an Array.sort, I am not actually sure what `this` is set to, but it is probably the Array you are sorting. A normal work around in this situation is to use another variable:

```
function some_object(...) {
   var so = this; // so = current `this`
   this.data = {...};

   this.do_something = function(...) {
      var arr = [...];

      arr.sort(function (a, b) {
         return so.data[a] - so.data[b];
      });  
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but is this the accepted method in Javascript? frankly looks like ugly hack :-)

Comment: also why you say "do_something" create closure? If I print `this` in do_somethiing I get correct object

Comment: No, its not a hack at all. The only other way is to specifically set what `this` means by binding it to the function. However, in this case, the `arr.sort` method does the calling, and you don't have a chance to set what `this` means. In an object like scenario, I actually declare `var base = this;` at the top, and then only use `base` to refer to that object within the scope of the function. That way, I don't have to guess when to use `this` and when to use `base`.

Comment: @zaharpopov Also, good catch, I updated my answer. It is not the `do_something` method, it is the anonymous function used to sort. In that context, `this` is probably equal to the Array, but I am not sure.

Comment: @z: it _is_ a hack, but required due to the incorrect implementation of *this* in the javascript spec. assigning var that = this; in the constructor is the standard method of retaining a valid reference to the object being created.

Comment: Now (10 years later), you can use the "fat arrow" syntax `() => {}` to be able to access `this` from the inner function

Answer (score 13):

You can bind the "outer" instance to the "inner" function by invoking the `bind` method on the inner function. Learn more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/eheobo/twv3emh7/1/

```
var foo = {
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    bar: function () {
        var printData = function(){
            this.data.forEach(a => console.info(a))
        }.bind(this)
        printData()
    }
}

foo.bar()
```

Comment: Or use an arrow function. I see you answered in 2016 so that should be an option.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a question from 2010, but now you should probably use arrow functions (and classes):

```
class some_object {
  constructor() {
    this.data = {...};
  }
  do_something(...) {
    let arr = [...];
    arr.sort((a, b) => this.data[a] - this.data[b]);
  }
}
```

Arrow functions don't have a `this`, so they use the one from the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

Since your sort algorithm doesn't depend on anything within `do_something` (other than that provided by the array), consider moving the function outside of `do_something`:

```
function some_object(...) {
   var so = this;
   so.data = {...};
   var comparator = function(a,b) { return so.data[a] - so.data[b]; };

   this.do_something = function(...) {
      var arr = [...].sort(comparator);
   }
}
```

Or, even provide a simple factory if you do this kind of sorting elsewhere:

```
var comparatorFactory = function(data) { return function(a,b) { return data[a] - data[b]; } };
function some_object(...) {
   var so = this;
   so.data = {...};
   var comparator = comparatorFactory(so.data);
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround (ES6) for callbacks which need outer `this` inside them:

```
wrapCallback(callback, that) {
  callback.wrappedCb = callback.wrappedCb || (function (...args) {
    return callback.bind(this)(that, ...args);
  });

  return callback.wrappedCb;
}
```

Usage example:

```
clicked(that, event) {
  // this: the clicked element
}

const that = this;
$('#button').click(wrapCallback(clicked, that));
```